# CT (current Transformer protection)

Tags: arduino, energy, meter

I try to read some value from CT. Everything is alright but sometimes I read some really high value on my arduino pin.
I was looking some information about the CT protection. People talked about diode because we don't want a value higher than 5V ( if it is higher we could burn the ATMEGA). Which type and where can I put it? I'm actually using this schematic:

[image: CT output connection to the arduino]

Comment: A resistor and zener diode will do the job for you.

Comment: Yes but which kind of diode should I take and where should I put it? Thanks for your answer

Comment: A 4.7 V zener diode in series with say 10 kohm resistor comming from the burden resistror and the input of your MCU.

Comment: @winny http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5803/why-do-people-answer-in-comments

Comment: My answers get deleted and/or downvoted unless there is only one answer to the question. This can be solved in many ways.